# PowerApps visibility of the next button based on the rating

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

So I am trying to make the Next button only visible when the user chooses a rating, but every time I apply one of these codes:
`If(Rating2.Value = 0; DisplayMode.Edit; Disabled)` or `If(Form9_3.Valid; DisplayMode.Edit; Disabled)`
The Next button stays grayed out... Any ideas on how to do this better?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0OlI.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function right now likely is on the button's Display Mode property. You want to put your function on the button's **Visible** property.

```
If(Rating2.Value = 0; false; true)
```

Make sure the default value of your Rating component is set to zero.

Comment: I tried this now, but the same happens... The next button gets hidden no matter which value is in the rating

Comment: I updated my solution. Switch the true and false values around, and make sure the default value for your rating component is set to zero.